# ajax file upload with response from php file

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

Is there a plug-in for file uploading with ajax that supports response? Meaning that I can return variable from my php file. Once the file gets uploaded, I want to ajax to respond the file path.

So far I only have an incomplete file upload: http://jsfiddle.net/Djp4J/

Comment: HTML5 is the only way you don't need flash to upload a File without a postback. But HTML 5 is not supported in IE and Opera. You can use flash for this. See [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for more information.

Comment: Niels that is incorrect. You don't need flash to upload files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this, but here is a popular library that simplifies it. https://github.com/valums/file-uploader